# Restar registros y eliminar - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, msql

Tengo tres tablas, una donde se registran los proveedores, otra donde se registran los créditos y la ultima donde se registran abonos.

lo que quiero lograr es que cuando se registren abonos en automático me reste y elimine los créditos menores al pago hecho por fecha de antigüedad

Por ejemplo:
tengo dos créditos uno de $500 (21/02/2022) y otro de $600 (22/02/2022) y si hago un abono de $700 me reste primero al del 21/02/2022 y después el del 22/02/2022, por ende el crédito del 21/02/2022 se eliminaría, y quedaría un resto de $400 al del 22/02/2022

como podría lograr esto?

**"ProviderCreditController"**

```
$totalcredit = ProviderCredit::join('providers', 'providers.id', '=', 'providers_credits.provider_id')
                                ->select('providers_credits.monto')
                                ->where('providers_credits.provider_id', $id)
                                ->sum('providers_credits.monto'); <---- Total de creditos
                                
    $totalabono = ProviderPayment::join('providers', 'providers.id', '=', 'providers_payments.provider_id')
                                ->select('providers_payments.monto')
                                ->where('providers_payments.provider_id', $id)
                                ->sum('providers_payments.monto'); <--- Total de Abonos

    $totalresta = $totalcredit - $totalabono;
```

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.

Comment: Una disculpa, me he ausentado por un tiempo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo que puedes hacer es obtener los créditos y los abonos en arreglos (Método `toArray()`), suponiendo que estas utilizando los `timestamp` en tu tabla (Tienes `created_at` y `updated_at`) los puedes ordenar de más antiguo a más reciente con el método `oldest()`

```
$creditos = ProviderCredit::join('providers', 'providers.id', '=', 'providers_credits.provider_id')
                                ->select('providers_credits.monto')
                                ->where('providers_credits.provider_id', $id)
                                ->oldest()->get()->toArray();
                                
$abonos = ProviderPayment::join('providers', 'providers.id', '=', 'providers_payments.provider_id')
                                ->select('providers_payments.monto')
                                ->where('providers_payments.provider_id', $id)
                                ->oldest()->get()->toArray();
```

Luego puedes crear un filtro para saber qué créditos tienen fecha anterior a cada abono (Desconozco los nombres de las columnas de tu tabla así que inventé unos nombres)

```
$creditosPrevios = [];
foreach ($fechasAbonos as $key => $abono) {
    $creditosPrevios[$key] = array_filter($fechasCreditos, function( $c ) use ($abono){ return $c < $abono; });
}

var_dump($creditosPrevios);
```

En `$creditosPrevios` tendrías un arreglo de arreglos, donde cada índice sería el índice de tu abono y adentro encontrarías todos los créditos con fechas anteriores a la fecha del crédito

Con `$creditosPrevios` puedes ir haciendo tus operaciones para aplicar el abono a los créditos anteriores a la fecha.

Comment: buenas noches agradezco tu ayuda!! pero lastimosamente no me ayudo del todo, intente algo similar pero solo recibí error ""BadMethodCallException con el mensaje 'Llamar al método no definido Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::toArray()'""

Comment: Intenta usar `->get()` antes de `->toArray()->`